# Is it possible to read __DATA__ with Config::General in Perl?

Tags: perl, configuration

I'd like to setup Config::General to read from the `__DATA__` section of a script instead of an external file. (I realize that's not normally how it works, but I'd like to see if I can get it going. A specific use case is so I can send a script example to another developer without having to send a separate config file.)

According to the [perldoc perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html), `$main::DATA` should act as a valid filehandle. I think [Config::General](http://p3rl.org/Config%3a%3aGeneral#SUBROUTINES-METHODS) should then be able to use `-ConfigFile => \$FileHandle` to read it, but it's not working for me. For example, this script will execute without crashing, but the `__DATA__` isn't read in.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Config::General;
use YAML::XS;

my $configObj = new Config::General(-ConfigFile => $main::DATA);

my %config_hash = $configObj->getall;

print Dump \%config_hash;

__DATA__

testKey = testValue
```

I also tried:

```
my $configObj = new Config::General(-ConfigFile => \$main::DATA);
```

and

```
my $configObj = new Config::General(-ConfigFile => *main::DATA);
```

and a few other variations, but couldn't get anything to work.

Is it possible to use Config::General to read config key/values from `__DATA__`?

Comment: It should be `Dump \%config_hash` not `Dump %config_hash`.

Comment: @BradGilbert - Yep. I just put in an edit to fix the reference for \%config_hash. Thanks.

Comment: All uses of `main::` in this thread are superfluous.

Comment: Good point @ikegami. This works fine: `my $configObj = new Config::General(-ConfigFile => \*DATA);`. I had started down the `main::` path when I couldn't get `__DATA__` to work out of the box. I was trying everything I could think of and the perldoc used it explicitly. That was the last attempt I made before breaking down and asking the question on S.O.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`-ConfigFile`](http://p3rl.org/Config%3a%3aGeneral#ConfigFile) requires a reference to a handle. This works:

```
my $configObj = Config::General->new(
    -ConfigFile => \*main::DATA
);
```

Comment: As @ikegami notes in the comments on the question. In my test case, it's not necessary to use `main::`. Removing it and using `my $configObj = new Config::General(-ConfigFile => \*DATA);` works just fine.

Answer (score 4):

The `DATA` handle is a glob, not a scalar.

Try `*main::DATA` instead of `$main::DATA`.

(and maybe try `\*main::DATA`. From the `Config::General` docs it looks like you are supposed to pass a filehandle argument as a reference.)

---

If the `-ConfigGeneral => filehandle` argument to the constructor doesn't do what you mean, an alternative is

```
new Config::General( -String => join ("", <main::DATA>) );
```

Comment: No luck with that one either.

Comment: it's actually `Config::General->new(-ConfigFile => \*main::DATA )` because of how Config::General is written.

Comment: Up-voting for the 'new Config::General( -String => join ("", <main::DATA>) );' alternative. That works as well as the accepted answer using '\*main::DATA' which Brad also pointed out.

Comment: Thanks @Brad Gilbert - I was trying to say `\*main::DATA` in my parenthetical remark but I got the markup wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Config::General;
use YAML::XS;

my $string;
{
    local $/;
    $string = <main::DATA>;
};
my $configObj = new Config::General(-String => $string);

my %config_hash = $configObj->getall;

use Data::Dumper;
warn Dumper(\%config_hash);

__DATA__

testKey = testValue
```

Comment: Thanks @Flimzy. It turns out I was able to use a reference to the filehandle and get it to do what I wanted more out of the box.